# Need to work on MS Word File with Python-docx without lossing Font properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I'm working on MS Word File, Edit and Replacing some Sentenace and save it in new Word-File

the problem it had been written in new word-file with new Font size, color , ltr , etc.

i want to keep the same Font and Paragraph Properties, is that possible ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.